# Redux-Saga response is undefined

Tags: axios, redux-saga

I'm having response is undefined on my request using redux-sagas and axios

```
export function* getCompanies({ payload }: any) {
  try {
    const { data: response } = yield call(api.get, '/companies-list', {
      params: {
        keyword: payload,
      },
    });
    console.error(response); // RETURNS NULL
    const { data } = response;
    yield put(handleFetchCompaniesAsync.success(data.companies));
  } catch ({ response }) {
    yield all([
      put(handleFetchCompaniesAsync.failure(response.data)),
      put(handleAsyncNotification(response.data)),
    ]);
  }
}
```

When trying to log the response it says `null`

Comment: Is `yield call(() => api.get('/companies-list', {
      params: {
        keyword: payload,
      }
    }));` also returning. null?

Comment: yes.. this is the error. https://i.imgur.com/nY7ZRA3.png
line 23 is inside the catch function

Comment: I think that the problem may be in Promise response and not `redux-saga`. Are you sure that response is coming from API?

Comment: yes it's coming from the API.. the result should be in JSON but I received an html response.

Answer (score 1):

Your saga looks ok and should be working

I think you should check your `api.get` endpoint. if you are not returning your `fetch` call, that might be the reason for this `undefined`.

For example:

```
--V-- this is probably what your are missing
return fetch('http://localhost:3000')
        .then((res) => {
            // bla bla bla
            return res.json();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // bla bla bla
        });
```